# jqGrid get multiple selected row cells value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

My jqGrid Script:

```
<script>
jQuery("#task-grid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "json",
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20,30],
    colNames:['ID','RESOURCE','ROLE','SITE', 'ALLOC. TYPE', 'UNIT (%)','HOURS'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'ID',key:true,index:'ID', width:50, align:'center',search:false,hidden: true},
        {name:'RESOURCE',index:'RESOURCE', width:150, sorttype:"text",align:'center',search:true},
        {name:'ROLE',index:'ROLE',width:120 ,align:'center',search:false},
        {name:'SITE',index:'SITE', width:120, align:'center',search:false},
        {name:'ALLOC. TYPE',index:'ALLOCATION_TYPE', align:'center',width:120,search:false },
        {name:'UNIT',index:'UNIT',align:'center',search:false},     
        {name:'HOURS',index:'HOURS', search:false, align:'center',sortable:false,editable:true}
    ],
    pager: "#page",
    shrinkToFit :true,
    autowidth: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname: 'RESOURCE',
        sortorder: "asc",
        multiselect: true,
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit : 'clientArray',
    caption: "Resource List"
}).navGrid('#page',{ edit:true,add:false,del:false,search:false,cloneToTop:true,refresh:false},
            {

             },{
             //add options

             },{

                        //msg: "do you really want delete this keyword? This delete affect on Eqms filter"

                });


                jQuery("#task-grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { autosearch: true  });
        var topPagerDiv = $('#grid_toppager')[0]; 
        jQuery("#grid_toppager_center", topPagerDiv).remove(); 
</script>
```

Below function is appending `rowId` value to in hidden input

```
 $("#addid").click(function(){
                var Ids = jQuery("#task-grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
                var empIds = $("input[type=hidden][name=user_id]").val(Ids);
});
```

Hidden Input

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value=""/>
```

Now I need to fetch the cell value inserted and for that I am using below function

```
var myGrid = $('#task-grid'),
selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
celValue = myGrid.jqGrid ('getCell', selRowId, 'HOURS');
```

The console log does show me the `rowId` selected but not its corresponding cell value. Also I am able to pass multiple `rowIds` checked in hidden input but not able to do for cell value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all `jQuery("#task-grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');` returns **array** of items. You can't assign the array as the value of some `<input>`. You can use comma separated list of items instead: `.val(Ids.join(","))` or you can use `JSON.stringify` alternatively. `.val(JSON.stringify(Ids))`.

To place values from some columns instead of ids you can define first an empty array and then fill it with the required values using `push` method. At the end you can use `.join(",")` or `JSON.stringify` to convert the array of items to the string which you can assign to `<input>`

```js
var $grid = $("#task-grid"), selIds = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow"), i, n,
    cellValues = [];
for (i = 0, n = selIds.length; i < n; i++) {
    cellValues.push($grid.jqGrid("getCell", selIds[i], "HOURS"));
}
alert(cellValues.join(","));
```

I recommend you additionally to use `gridview: true` option in the grid to improve the performance and to fix `name:'ALLOC. TYPE'`. If you need to read some exotic formatted input elements the you should use `jsonmap`, but to hold the `name` property so that it have no spaces, dots and other [meta-characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). I recommend you to use all `index` the same as the `name`. In the case you can remove `index` properties at all from `colModel`. If you use mostly `align:'center', search:false` then I recommend you to change defaults for `colModel` items by usage `cmTemplate: {align: 'center', search: false}`. It allows you to remove many properties from `colModel` and makes it more readable and better to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.makeArray(grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow').map(function(elem) {
    return grid.jqGrid('getCell', elem, 'nameCELL');
}));
```